# How to combine multi_match and two boolean filters

Tags: elasticsearch

I can successfully combine a `multi_match` query with a filter like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must":{
                "multi_match":{
                    "query": "ny gammal",
                    "fields": ["title", "description^1.4"],
                    "type": "cross_fields"
                }
            },
            "filter":{
                "range": {
                    "modelYear": {"gte": "2017"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to add another filter (using `and` because I want both conditions to be fulfilled), Elasticsearch tells me that my query is incorrect:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must":{
                "multi_match":{
                    "query": "ny gammal",
                    "fields": ["title", "description^1.4"],
                    "type": "cross_fields"
                }
            },
            "filter":{
                "and":[
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "modelYear": {"gte": "2017"}
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "location": "Kumla"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "[and] query malformed, no start_object after query name",
                "line": 12,
                "col": 15
            }
        ],
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[and] query malformed, no start_object after query name",
        "line": 12,
        "col": 15
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

How can I achieve what I want? I've tried many different things, so far unsuccessfully.

To help you understand, I want to do the `multi_match` to get the scored documents, then only keep the ones that pass the two filters, which are `"location" == "Kumla"` and `modelYear >= 2017`.

I've looked everywhere in the docs, and to my great surprise there seems to be nothing that talks about how to achieve this, i.e. combining `term` and `range` filters.

I'm using Elasticsearch 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, use `filter` as a simple array since `filter` clauses must match all.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "ny gammal",
          "fields": [
            "title",
            "description^1.4"
          ],
          "type": "cross_fields"
        }
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "modelYear": {
              "gte": "2017"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "location": "Kumla"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Refer: [Combine queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html#bool-filter)

Comment: "since `filter` clauses must match all". I don't understand this reasoning. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: all the clauses inside the `filter` must be matched i.e., equivalent of `AND` but run in non-scoring mode. Refer: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html#bool-filter